# History pushstate back & forward functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, browser-history, pushstate

I just made a website where all pages are loaded using ajax. Now I am trying to make the back & forward browser buttons work. The back button was quite easy, all I had to do was this:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    get_page_content(location.href);
});
```

Where `get_page_content()` is the function I use to get and replace the page content when a link is clicked. And this is how I use the pushstate inside `get_page_content()`:

```
window.history.pushState('', '', url);
```

Them problem is whenever I go back the forward button is not available. How can I use the forward button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I had `window.history.pushState('', '', url);` inside `get_page_content()` which then was called each time `onpopstate` event fired and eventually there was nothing to go forward to. I simply moved `pushState` outside of `get_page_content()` and everything works. Here's what I currently have:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not([href^="#"])', function(e) {

  if ( this.host === window.location.host ) {

    e.preventDefault()

    get_page_content($(this).attr('href'));
    window.history.pushState('', '', url);

  }

});

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {

    get_page_content(location.href);

});

function get_page_content(url) {
  // ...
}
```